# Support command discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have created support command. But I want it to be more advanced. Everything works in my code but I want to add a function that my bot will dm me with a message content someone dmed bot. Well that's confusing I know but let me explain it with my code:

````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import DiscordUtils


intents = discord.Intents.default()

intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "=", intents = intents)


@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def support(ctx):
    author = ctx.author
    await ctx.message.add_reaction('<a:check12:810961073746345985>')
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = 'What do you want to do?',
        description = '',
        color = 0
    )

    embed.set_footer(text='007 support')
    embed.add_field(name='Report a bug, react:', value="1️⃣", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Submit suggestion, react:', value="2️⃣", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Talk to bot owner, react:', value="3️⃣", inline=False)

    msg = await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)

    await msg.add_reaction("1️⃣")
    await msg.add_reaction("2️⃣")
    await msg.add_reaction("3️⃣")

    
    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ["1️⃣", "2️⃣", "3️⃣"]

    while True:
        try:
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=60, check=check)

            if str(reaction.emoji) == "1️⃣":
                embed = discord.Embed(color=0)
                embed.set_author(name=f"007", icon_url="")
                embed.add_field(name='Report a bug', value="Describe a bug here. 007 will try to fix it.")
                embed.set_footer(text="007 support")
                await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)

                user = client.get_user(int(MY_ID))
                await user.send(embed=embed)

            if str(reaction.emoji) == "2️⃣":
                embed = discord.Embed(color=0)
                embed.set_author(name=f"007", icon_url="")
                embed.add_field(name='Submit suggestion', value="Submit your suggestion here. 007 owner will review it as fast as possible")
                embed.set_footer(text="007 support")
                await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)

                
                user = client.get_user(int(MY_ID))
                await user.send(embed=embed)


            if str(reaction.emoji) == "3️⃣":
                embed = discord.Embed(color=0)
                embed.set_author(name=f"007", icon_url="")
                embed.add_field(name='Talk to a owner', value='Your code is 240348. Type this in any channel: ```=talk <your code>``` then follow instructions')
                embed.set_footer(text="007 support")
                await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)
    
    
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await msg.delete()
````

As you see in options(1, 2) bot send embed to `ctx.author` and to me. But I want bot to send embed message to me and author's answer with author name. For example:

```
if str(reaction.emoji) == "2️⃣":
                embed = discord.Embed(color=0)
                embed.set_author(name=f"007", icon_url="")
                embed.add_field(name='Submit suggestion', value="Submit your suggestion here. 007 owner will review it as fast as possible")
                embed.set_footer(text="007 support")
                await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)

                
                user = client.get_user(int(MY_ID))
                await user.send(embed=embed)
                await user.send(f'{answer} {author.name}
```

In last line there is author's answer/message. Is this possible to do this? If yes let me know how. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. Do you want that when someone DM your bot, the bot sends a DM to you with the name of the User that sent a DM to your bot, as well as the message that was sent ?

Comment: Yeah thats what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

To make it so that your bot forwards the message it got to you, you simply need to put code for the [on_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message) [event](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot%20event#discord.ext.commands.Bot.event). This bit of code will make that every time the bot receives a direct message, it will send to the user with id MY_ID the content of the received message, followed by the name of the author of the message

```
@client.event
async def on_message(self, message: Message):
    if not isinstance(message.channel, DMChannel):  # This is to check if the message was received via DM
        return
    user = client.get_user(int(MY_ID))
    await user.send(content=f"{message.content} received from {message.author.name}")
```

If you want to also forward files and images this might require more checks such as checking if [Message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message) has attachements, etc.

You can find more documentation about the Message class on https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message